# MySQL 3 column unique constraint not working, possibly due to NULL

Tags: mysql, sql, null, unique-constraint

This is my table, `GameAdmin`:

```
game_id   company_id    user_id
1         5             NULL
1         5             NULL
1         NULL          2
1         NULL          3
1         NULL          3
```

It links games to entities that can edit them (either a company or a user).

I have a `UNIQUE` index on all columns, but as you can see it's not working as expected.

What is wrong? Is it because of the `NULL`s?

---

I know I could make it work by changing the structure to:

```
game_id   admin_type    admin_id
1         company       5
1         company       5
1         user          2
1         user          3
1         user          3
```

But that's not compatible with my JPA/Hibernate setup, or at least very inconvenient, because it doesn't allow me to set the relations like this:

```
@ManyToOne(optional=true)
private User user;

@ManyToOne(optional=true)
private Company company;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh, the solution is so simple. I split the constraint up, so there's one for `game_id` and `company_id`, and for `game_id` and `user_id`.

Answer (score 0):

It is because of the NULL value. They are not considered unique. If you don't have Foreign Keys on those fields, you might use 0 instead of NULL.

Answer (score 0):

If you know (and I mean **know**, not **guess**) that you will never have more than 2 possible classes (user/company), just use negative IDs on one of them.

- I know this is not 1NF
- I know this is hacky
- I know this is not really beautifull

But IMHO this is on the acceptable side of the "thin red line".

Comment: I don't think that'd work. It'd violate the foreign key constraint, and probably trip up Hibernate. And I already found the proper solution anyway :P But thanks for thinking with me